# fopen with dynamic filename is not working

Tags: bash, fopen, sh

I need to make a web site on which people can upload data files that after some treatment will be plotted using the jpgraph. The file is analyzed with a bash script called analfile.sh. The bash script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
fecha=`date +%s`
mv $1 $fecha.dat
echo $fecha.dat
```

So, it gives back another file which name is like: 1321290921.dat. That is the file that I need to plot.

This my current php code:

```
$target_path = "/home/myhome";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['rdata']['name']); 
$target_file = basename( $_FILES['rdata']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rdata']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {   
    echo "The file ".  $target_file. " has been uploaded";    
    chdir('/home/myhome');    
    $filetoplot=shell_exec('./analfile.sh'.' '.$target_file);    
} else{    
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please <a href=\"index.html\">try again!
</a>";
}

//$filetoplot="1321290921.dat"  
echo "<br>The file to be opened is ".  $filetoplot. "<br>";

if ($file_handle = fopen("$filetoplot", 'r')) {     
  while ( $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle) ) {  
    $parts = explode('.', $line_of_text);
    echo $line_of_text ;
    print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. $parts[2]. "<br>";   
  }   
fclose($file_handle);    
}
```

I have permissions to read and write on the target directory. I find strange that if I uncomment the line $filetoplot="1321290921.dat" then the script works perfectly. I guess I am doing something stupid since this is my first code in php but after some hours googling I was not able to find a solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Double check that you're not running PHP in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'm seeing is that you don't append trailing slash (`/`) to your home path, so that the path would be like `/home/myhomefoo` rather than `/home/myhome/foo`.

You should also move `$target_file` earlier, and reuse that within `$target_path`. There's no reason to do the same thing twice.

If that doesn't help, we'll see what goes next.